# Custom matcher not asserting in Astrolabe/Protractor + Jasmine test

Tags: jasmine, pageobjects, matcher, protractor, astrolabe

I'm writing some page-object driven tests using [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) and [Astrolabe](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe).

Jasmine is being used to implement `describe`/`it` style specs.

Adding custom matchers won't work using `this.addMatchers` (`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toContainLowered'`), so I used [this guide](http://tobyho.com/2012/01/30/write-a-jasmine-matcher/) to implement them.

It seems to be working, until I look closely at the output of my test run:

```
$> grunt test:func
Running "test:func" (test) task

Running "shell:protractor" (shell) task
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
..

Finished in 6.727 seconds
2 tests, 1 assertion, 0 failures
```

Here is my code:

```
var loginPage = require('./../pages/loginPage');

describe('Login page', function () {

    var ptor = loginPage.driver;

    beforeEach(function () {
        jasmine.Matchers.prototype.toContainLowered = function (expected) {
            return this.actual.toLowerCase().indexOf(expected) > -1;
        };
        loginPage.go();
        ptor.waitForAngular();
    });

    it('should display login page', function () {
        expect(loginPage.currentUrl).toEqual(ptor.baseUrl);
    });

    it('should display an error when the username or password is incorrect', function() {
        loginPage.login('bad', 'credentials');
        ptor.waitForAngular();
        expect(loginPage.lblError.getText()).toContainLowered('invalid username and/or password');
        // expect(loginPage.lblError.getText()).toContain('Invalid Username and/or Password');
    });

});
```

If I uncomment the last line and remove the `toContainLowered` matcher, I get the proper output:

```
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures
```

I'm having a really difficult time debugging this promise-based code, and any efforts to put a `console.log(this.actual.toLowerCase().indexOf(expected) > -1);` will print `false`, which is confusing.

I even tried replacing the entire function definition with just `return false;`. Which still does not do anything. Finally, I tried passing no argument to the matcher, which should have thrown an Invalid Argument Error or something.

How do I define my own matchers in Jasmine when using Protractor/Astrolabe tests?

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems with matchers, in particular with the .not matchers, which all seem to not work.  I hypothesise that protractor is extending the Jasmine matchers to deal with the promises, and that that extension hasn't been applied to the .not, or to the custom matchers.

In my case, I wanted a .not.toMatch, and so I just wrote a convoluted regex that gave me what I wanted, with the not embedded in the regex.

I note that your matcher is called "toContainLowered", so perhaps you're looking for lowercase, and therefore you could instead do this with a regex by using .toMatch?

The issue I raised on this on the protractor github is here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/266

I also see, in this code file: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/jasminewd/spec/adapterSpec.js, that the last commit is marked as "patched matcher should understand not".  That might either fix the custom matchers for you, or provide an indication of what needs to be done to fix that custom matcher.

EDIT: now looking further into that issue thread, I see you've already been there.  Which makes my answer somewhat superfluous.  :-)

Comment: Also, the [`.not` issue has been fixed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/137d8040778215fd841654d3ca465b71f8719ea5). Not matchers should work now.